# perl logical/conditional expression possible?

Tags: perl

I need to proccess a waveform from a text file.
I need to remove an element only when **Y2-Y1 < 30**
Currently I run

```
s/[0-9.]{3,} [0-9.]{3,} m\n[0-9.]{3,} [0-9.]{3,} l\nS/0 0 m\n0 0 l\nS/g
```

but this removes more than I need. Is this even possible in perl?
The format is

```
X1 Y1 m
X2 Y2 l
S
```

Sample Data:

```
1560 5940 m
1560 5374 l
S

1548 5964 m
1572 5964 l
S

1572 5964 m
1572 5940 l
S
```

Desired output:

```
1560 5940 m
1560 5374 l
S

0 0 m
0 0 l
S

0 0 m
0 0 l
S
```

Comment: Perl isn't sed...you don't have to use a regex for *everything*. :)

Comment: This is fairly trivial to solve if you're not married to doing all the work inside a single regular expression.

Comment: Properly parse entries and just `next` your loop with simple literal `if ($Y2 - $Y1 < 30)`.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov When the original poster said "remove", he meant "zero out", so skipping with `next` isn't going to get the desired output.

Comment: The sample output isn't correct. 5374 - 5940 = -566, which is less than 30. The first record of output should be zeroed out according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This expects to be called with your input filename as an argument:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @queue;

while (<>) {
    next unless /\S/;
    push(@queue, $_);

    if (/^S/) {
        my ($x1, $y1) = split(/\s+/, shift(@queue));
        my ($x2, $y2) = split(/\s+/, shift(@queue));

        if ($y2 - $y1 < 30) {
            $x1 = $y1 = $x2 = $y2 = 0;
        }

        print "$x1 $y1 m\n$x2 $y2 l\nS\n\n";
        @queue = ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is looking like a record what about reading it like a records:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "S\n\n";

while (<>) {
    my ( $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2 ) = m/(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+m\n(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+l/;
    next unless defined $x1;
    $_ = "0 0 m\n0 0 l\nS\n\n" if $y1 - $y2 < 30;
}
continue {
    print;
}
```

BTW, your example output doesn't correspond with your `Y2-Y1 < 30` condition.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a job for `if() {}` instead of regex.

Apologies if the following needs editing - my Perl is rusty.

My snippet assumes two input arrays `@y1` and `@y2`, both of the same known length `$array_length`.

```
my $i = 0;
my $y1 = 0;
my $y2 = 0;

for ( i = 0; i < $array_length; i++ )
{
    $y1 = $y1[i];
    $y2 = $y2[i];
    if ( $y2 - $y1 < 30 )
    {
        #your output code here
    }
    else
    {
        #output 0s here
    }
}
```

There's ways to simplify that to have only one output block.